# Azure Function .NET Core 3.1 C# unit test case with nUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions

I need to create a unit test cases in Azure Function .NET Core using C# and NUnit framework. Please share a good example with links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit tests shouldn’t include the Function App entry point, just like they shouldn’t include Asp.Net controllers, or the Main method of a Console app.